# How much homotopy theory can you bootstrap off a circle/integers?

Tags: homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory

I've been trying to figure out some homotopy stuff with regards to categories.

A lot of theorem provers have good support for integers.
Not so many have good support for quotient types.
Setoids help but they're still a massive pain.
The fundamental group of the circle is equivalent to addition of integers.
So the circle can be defined directly in terms of integers.

How much homotopy theory can I bootstrap from the circle/integers in preference to fiddling with setoids and quotients?

I'm wondering if I can get away without any setoids/quoitents at all just by using integers/circles.

I know a functor out of the circle is a loop and you can take the product of circles to obtain toroids. But the suspension seems to require the smash product.

I have a feeling like maybe what I want is something to do with stabilization and spectrum objects but I don't understand those. Maybe homology? Every Abelian group can be represented by a Z-Module so maybe this is what I want. I don't really get it though.

In pseudocoq.

```
Instance Circle: Groupoid := {
   object := unit ;
   mor _ _ := Z ;
   id _ := 0 ;
   compose _ _ _ f g := f + g ;
   invert _ _ x := -x ;
}.
```

I'm exploring Cubical Agda right now but this style still looks sort of interesting.

Comment: Well, the loop space of the circle is huge. It has separate path-connected components, one per integer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_space?wprov=sfti1

Comment: Of course you're quite right I got the terminology wrong.